# Mono<> with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

I ran into a problem while trying to use Mono from Reactor with Spring Cloud Stream and can't really figure out what's going on.

Imagine I have a listener like this:

```
@StreamListener
@Output(Urls.OUTUT)
public Flux<String> expandUrls(@Input(Urls.INPUT) Flux<String> urlFormats)
{
    return urlFormats
        .map(this::expandUrl)
        .flatMapIterable(urls -> urls);
}
```

So it's basically expanding a url formatted like this `http://www.example.com/page/%d` to something like this

`http://www.example.com/page/1`

`http://www.example.com/page/2`

`http://www.example.com/page/3`

It works as expected, but when I tried to do it like this:

```
@StreamListener
@Output(Urls.OUTPUT)
public Flux<String> expandUrls(@Input(Urls.INPUT) Mono<String> urlFormats)
{
    return urlFormats
        .repeat(3)
        .zipWith(pageNumbers)
        .map(this::formatUrl);
}
```

where pageNumber is `Flux.fromStream(Stream.iterate(1, p -> p+1).limit(3))`

I get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A method annotated with @StreamListener may use @Input or @Output annotations only in declarative mode and for parameters that are binding targets or convertible from binding targets.
```

I got rid of the exception by doing it like this

```
@StreamListener(value = Urls.INPUT)
@Output(Urls.OUTPUT)
public Flux<String> expandUrls(Mono<String> urlFormats)
{
    return urlFormats
        .repeat(3)
        .zipWith(pageNumbers)
        .map(this::formatUrl);
}
```

But now I get this:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'http': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: http://www.example.com/page-%d,1,0.html;
```

My question is then: how to use Mono with Spring Cloud Stream. Is it even possible to use it like this? If yes, then how to do it? 
Oh, I'm using Kafka as broker with the kafka-starter.

Comment: That is just because SCSt doesn't support `Mono` for that use-case. Only `Flux` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream StreamListener's @Input parameter type supports the reactor type `Flux` only as it fits well for reactive streaming applications than having `Mono` at the @Input parameter type.